# Webpack loading bootstrap only when needed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I am using WebPack and React to bundle a calendar-widget thats used in other websites by customers using a snippet we give them. They copy the snippet e.g. into a wordpress site or any other page they want to show the calendar.

```
<!-- This is the begin of the widget code. -->
<div id="widget" style="margin-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 60px"></div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='widgets.min.js'></script>
<script>Widgets.default.config({ domain: "", selector: "#widget" });Widgets.default.calendar.new().render();</script>
<!-- This is the end of the widget code. -->
```

The problem is, that our widget uses bootstrap and if the site the widget snippet is placed also uses bootstrap, we import it twice which leads to display errors.

Question is, how to load bootstrap only when its not already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If they are already copying the snippet just to use the widget, why not make it a requirement for them to copy the bootstrap cdn as well? this way you dont have to import it

Comment: Yes, that we will do if there is no other solution. Thanks